# SpringJdbcTemplate queryForLlist where in,or

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I query with `spring jdbcTemplate`,the `sql` language:`select * from tb_user where name='name1' and sex='0' or name='name2' and sex='0'or  ......`,

how can I use the `jdbcTemplate` to do it?

I don't express well.What I want to express is like:

querying users by two columns but not throughing appending sql.

```
sql:"select * from tb_user where name=? and sex=?";
entity:User{String name,int sex};
params:List<User>   
   just like(user1("windy",0),user2("windy2",0),user3("windy3",1))
```

then I use jdbcTemplate just like:

```
queryForList("select * from tb_user where name=? and sex=?", List<MapperClass> , List<User>);
```

the important point is :the sql is "select * from tb_user where name=? and sex=?",and won't be appended.

Comment: google it. Do you have a specific case you wanna clarify?

Comment: I don't express well.What's I want to express like querying users by two columns but not throughing appending sql.  

queryForList("select * from tb_user where name=? and sex=?", List<MapperClass> , new String[]{"name1","0","name2","0"});

Answer (score 0):

use the following method.

```
queryForList(String sql, Class<T> elementType, Object... args)
```

**example:**

```
queryForList("select * from tb_user where name=? and sex=? or name=? and sex=? ", List<MapperClass> , new String[]{"name1","0","name2","0"});
```

refer this url to know how to create a mapper class 
http://www.javatpoint.com/RowMapper-example